# pagination in a view which allows you to filter

Tags: django-views

in a view that allows you to filter by element such as searches and especially filters by category or by series is it possible to make a pagination? if yes you can give me a view which uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. A [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) can do this, since the pagination is done on the result of `get_queryset`. Hence you can implement this as:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from app.models import MyModel

class MyModelListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return qs.filter(some_field__icontains=self.request.GET.get('search', ''))
```

If you both paginate and search, then there are two items in the *querystring*,, hence the pagination URLs are more cumbersome:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?search={{ request.GET.search|urlencode }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
{% endif %}
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?search={{ request.GET.search|urlencode }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you i know it's possible now but i would like to with request and not listview. request has several advantages

Comment: @azsd: the request is accessible through `self.request`, like you can already see that in the `self.request.GET.get('search', '')`.

Comment: @azsd: why would you lose these? You can override the `get_context_data` and inject these, or use for example `setup` and patch the request. You can do anything in a CBV that you can do in an FBV, since it is just a class that eleminates a lot "boilerplate" through inheritance. After all Django itself moved all its authentication views, and admin views to class-based views.

Comment: listen I think I removed the comment where I said that with listview you lose a lot of items because I respect your choice of ease even if it is the worst choice in the world. know that all the real IT pro me too even if I have some gaps we are gradually erasing the use of generic view and that's why when I find someone talking to me about generic view here I was very surprised normally in a pseudo pro forum find a lot I stay professional so I would not say name but here